# Perl pod2html cannot resolve email link

Tags: perl, perldoc

Maybe I'm not doing this right, but for a lot of [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) [link examples](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html#Formatting-Codes) the code just doesn't work in [pod2html](http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2html.html).

For instance:

```
Owner: L<Eric Fossum|mailto:myemail@gmail.com>
```

Seems to work with `C:\perldoc filename` and `C:\pod2text filename`, but `C:\pod2html --title=SomeText --outfile=filename.html filename` outputs:

```
pod2html.bat: filename: cannot resolve L<Eric Fossum|mailto:myemail@gmail.com> in paragraph 6.
```

Do you guys think it's an issue with my install or my code? How do I fix it?

**Update:**

Here are my module versions:

```
Can't locate Pod.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...) at (eval 1) line 2.
Pod::Html           : 1.09
Pod::Simple         : 3.14
Pod::Simple::XHTML  : 3.14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me with Perl v5.16.2.  I'm using the following Pod:

```
=pod

Owner: L<Eric Fossum|mailto:myemail@gmail.com>

=cut
```

Inside the body of the HTML, it returns:

```
<p>Owner: <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">Eric Fossum</a></p>
```

Comment: Hmm... I am using 5.012, but I don't think that should be an issue. How do I verify?

Comment: It's possible the issue is in Pod::Simple::XHTML. I'm using 3.23. I would try upgrading Pod::Simple::XHTML on your end and then testing your script again.

Comment: Just to clarify, Pod::Html is in core, which is why I mentioned my version of Perl. It doesn't appear to have changed between our versions, though.  Also, from a quick look, it looks like it hands off the Pod generation anyway, so the issue is likely somewhere in the Pod::Simple dist. See https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.16.2/ext/Pod-Html/lib/Pod/Html.pm#L704

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a link such as Lhttp://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/RColorBrewer/html/ColorBrewer.html> in perl 5.14.2. As oalders commented, pod2html uses the Pod::Html, which has been a core module since perl 5.4. Thus, I tested different versions of perl and found that the issue has been solved between perl 5.14.2 and perl 5.16.2.

So, the solution is to simply upgrade perl.